# C++ with libtcod not allowing TCODColor type declaration

Tags: c++, libtcod

I am attempting to make a simple rouge like game with c++ and libtcod. I am attempting to compile code that declares a col variable with TCODColor

`TCODColor col;`

and this is the actual error:

`error: TCODColor does not name a type`

The error occues in the header file but I have included the necessary `#include "libtcod.h"` in the .cpp file. I have no idea why it will not allow me to declare this type. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to include `libtcod.hpp` not `libtcod.h`, the latter is for C, not C++ and `TCODColor` is in the C++ version.

Comment: THANK YOU! Such a simple problem that I missed it!